# Playing an mp3 live stream with Flash/Actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mp3, flash-cs5, audio-streaming

I'm completely new to ActionScript and Flash. I need to create a flash plugin that can play audio that is streaming live in an mp3 format.  I would have used the new html5 `<audio>` tag except that they don't support mp3, and I have thus resorted to Flash.

I have managed to play remote mp3 files and local files, but am struggling to get the following to work with streaming data:

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://ip:port");
var s:Sound = new Sound(req);
fl_SC = s.play();
```

I have a feeling it's because it's not just a simple URL request..  How would one accomplish such a task?

Comment: If it's a stream, you may just need to use NetStream instead of Sound. You'll have to give us an example of the URL to get a real idea what you're up against. Please do! Cheers-

Answer (score 1):

Pass the URLRequest object to a Sound.load method.

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://ip:port");
var s:Sound = new Sound();
s.load(req);
fl_SC = s.play();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this yields the same results.. I don't hear anything.  I know the stream works, because I can open it in VLC and verify that it is mp3-encoded.

Comment: This is the same thing the OP posted.